# How to design and being prepared for large concurrent iterations

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I could use your help in setting up my database structure the most optimal way (future proof). 
This to facilitate data scraped from booking sites based on specific customer profiles. After this I would like to build dashboards with pivots, etc for insights through mainly `php`.

Situation:

```
- 10k customer profiles per month 
- through 5 sites 
- with about 125 results 
- with 20 attributes (pricing etc) per result
```

That are minimal 125mio pieces of data for this first iteration...

Following iteration could deviate in > # sites and new/partially overlapping customer profiles (I guess 20k).

Restriction: 
- `one MySQL database so far`

I've thought about limitations of columns, rows and tables, and these are the options that I could think of. Maybe/hopefully you have better suggestions or point me to one below:

> 1. 1 table with all profiles, than create table per profile and save the data (# sites, # results, # attributes) per row in this one
> 2. Same as 1. But to save the amounts of rows per profile table, a blob with per site data (# results and # attributes). But since I've
>      never worked with aspecifically blobs, I don't know how easy/difficult
>      that would be to get the data out of there to analyze.

Comment: Duplicate of http://localhost/forums/list.php?ft=125:643569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second solution has many more concurrency limitations than the first one does.  If two processes want to write tot he same blob, you have many more locking considerations than if everything is decomposed.

Normalize your data at first. Then as you grow, only denormalize where you have to.  Normalization is a sort of global optimization, while denormalization has both costs and benefits.

Comment: Thanks Chris.

Rick also helped my and as well as the problem on the max amount of rows as well as the insert (via load data) was not a concern after all.

Problem solved ;-)